# ServletRequest/ServletResponse manipulation

Tags: java, servlet-filters

I want to implement an advanced Java servlet filter for processing batch requests on API server. Something similar to the [Facebook batch request API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/). The idea is:

- setup servlet filter on given url
- override `doFilter(request, response)`, here:
- parse list of partial requests from body, for each:

  - prepare partial request
  - call `chain.doFilter(partialRequest, partialResponse)`
  - remember partial response
- render response with list of partial responses

I am able to construct `HttpServletRequestWrapper` for each partial request, and create `HttpServletResponseWrapper` with some output stream cheating, but this is a bit hard, I have to change almost all parts, path, body, headers etc.

Are there any good library for **request/response manipulation**, or better request/response wrapper class?

Comment: What do you mean by partial request?

Comment: Batch request body contains several partial request as JSON array of objects with attributes `path`, `headers`, `body` etc. The filter should read this objects, creates real request and call next filter in chain. That means: one outside request will be processed as many different partial requests, which will be passed to next filter.

Comment: Why do you want to create a separate request for each task. Is multit-hreading on the backend not an option?

Comment: This will be optional only use of standard API resources, especially for mobile app as client. Partial requests can be processed in parallel as regular requests, moreover they are relatively fast. Batch processing is hack for network latency problems in mobile networks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retrospective update for those you interested:

Finally I have dived for one full day into `HttpServletRequestWrapper` and `HttpServletResponseWrapper` dark forest and have done fully functional batch filter providing multiple requests to servlet and aggregating responses.

Unfortunately this filter must be the last filter in a row just before servlet, because subsequent filters are called only once.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to consolidate as many requests as possible into one, but I don't think you would de-consolidate them on the back-end.

I think your approach complicates things, and I'm not even sure if it's possible to spawn new HttpRequest objects on the back-end.

Drop the filters, stick with one request (on the front-end and back-end), and spawn a new Thread for each task in your request.

Comment: I understand your advice. The servlet in my case is Jersey REST server. Jersey provides many useful things for me: request parsing, choosing controller based on `@Path` annotations and body deserialization based on `@Consumes` annotations. Thats fine, but if I'll do process tasks (partial requests) here in servlet, I'll can't provide those useful things for partial requests. I want to keep tasks in batch in request format. For example see similar [Facebook batch API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/)

Comment: @mschayna I think now I understand what you're trying to do. I assumed all partial requests would go to the same URL. Still, I'm not aware of any API that would spawn new requests. The only thing that comes to my mind is java.net, but that would require a lot of manual labor which is something you're trying to avoid. Sorry.